# Using manual STAF commands on Linux

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, staf

I've recently started working with STAF and couldn't get 2 machines to communicate with each other. One of those machines is a Linux ec2-instance on AWS and can't be pinged.

I was planning on pinging STAF from one virtual machine to another to see if the company firewall could be the cause of this but I can't seem to use commands on linux (like "staf local ping ping" on windows for example). When I try to run STAFProc with gdb (in /usr/local/staf/bin) I get the following error.

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /usr/local/staf/bin/STAFProc
/bin/bash: /usr/local/staf/bin/STAFProc: No such file or directory
```

(The STAFProc file is there though. Does gdb work from another directory?)

I'm not exactly experienced with STAF, AWS or even Linux so any help to get me started with debugging would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Though it is a bit long since the question is asked and the op seem to figure it out already, I might still post my solution as well.

There is a possibility that it is caused by trying to open a 32bit binary on a 64bit device.

If you are working on Debian based os, try

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
```